# c++ runtime instantiation of member parameter

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++11

As the title says I would like to initiate a Store object whose type is determined at runtime only. I initially went for a virtual class, 2 derived classes but quickly faced the need for templates.

The class `O` has a pointer to an interface `BaseStore` for these Store objects. Moreover since I also need to call the right functions for the Derived classes `Store1` and `Store2`, I used a dynamic cast in a template function of the interface.

Since I am new to c++, I wonder if this design has flaws and if there is any place for improvements. Thanks for your expertise!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct BaseStore {
   virtual ~BaseStore() {}
   template<typename S> void test() const;
};

struct Store1 : public BaseStore {
   Store1(int j) { this->i = j; }
   void test() const { cout << i << endl; }
 private:
   int i = 1;
};

struct Store2 : public BaseStore {
   Store2(string s) { this->i = s; }
   void test() const { cout << i << endl; }
 private:
   string i = "2";
};

template<typename S> void BaseStore::test() const
{
dynamic_cast<const S&>(*this).test();
}

class O {
  public:
    O(int i) {
      this->type = i;
      switch (this->type) {
       case 1: basestore = new Store1(42); break;
       case 2: basestore = new Store2("lol"); break;
      }
    }
    ~O() { delete basestore; }
  void test() const {
    switch (this->type) {
     case 1: basestore->test<Store1>(); break; 
     case 2: basestore->test<Store2>(); break;
    }
  }
 private:
   int type;
   BaseStore* basestore;
 };
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a code review.

Comment: I would say what you're trying to accomplish is a [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: I post code to show that - at least - I have tried something. The original code is just bigger and since it is hard to explain to with words I do it with some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe virtual functions and the factory pattern will help here, as in:

```
struct BaseStore
{
    virtual ~BaseStore() = default;
    virtual void test() const = 0;

    BaseStore() = default;
    BaseStore(BaseStore const&) = delete;
    BaseStore(BaseStore&&) = delete;
    BaseStore& operator=(BaseStore&&) = delete;
    BaseStore& operator=(BaseStore const&) = delete;

};

struct Store1 : public BaseStore {
   Store1(int j) : i(j) {}
   void test() const override { std::cout << i << std::endl; }
 private:
   int i = 1;
};

struct Store2 : public BaseStore {
   Store2(std::string s) : i(std::move(s)) {}
   void test() const override { std::cout << i << std::endl; }
 private:
   std::string i = "2";
};

class O {
public:
    O(int i) : type(i), basestore(StoreFactory(i)) {}
    void test() const { basestore->test(); }

private:

    static std::unique_ptr<BaseStore> StoreFactory(int i)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 1: return std::unique_ptr<Store1>(new Store1(42));
        case 2: return std::unique_ptr<Store2>(new Store2("lol"));
        default: throw std::runtime_error("Don't know what kind of Store you want");
        }
    }

   int type;
   std::unique_ptr<BaseStore> basestore;
 };
```

Comment: Definitely the way to go. I didn't know about the factory design. Thanks!